# Cisco UC Integration for Lync does not switch back Lync status after a call

Tags: cisco, lync, microsoft-office-2013

We use [Cisco UC Integration for Microsoft Lync](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/unified-communications/uc-integration-tm-microsoft-lync/index.html) with Office 2013. The integration does not seem to be as good as with Office 2010 (we have a separate icon for the running program, not [the expected integration](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucimoc/8_5/english/faq/b_faq_olh_85.html#reference_A4CFD1C81FA04DC4AEF094971FC6E5F9), but this is not a major issue).

When receiving a call, Lync status switches to *"Do Not Disturb"* mode but does not switch back to the previous one (*"Available"* for instance) when the call is over.

- Is there a particular setting for this behavior or is it a bug?
- Is there a way to disable this functionality (better have no switch at all than no switch back)?